# CakePhp 3.x Auth fails with multiple identical usernames

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My login Auth works as expected but when multiple accounts use the same username the Authentication fails.

User 1:
 - username: Foo
 - password: Test1

User 2:
 - username: Foo
 - password: Test2

User 3:
 - username: Foo1
 - password: Test1

In my settings User 1 & 2 will fail.

Where can I let Cake check the useraccounts for username AND password and not only the username in `identify()`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to authenticate users with a unique identifier instead, for example the email address? What if two users select an identical username + password combination? If you store passwords with proper unique hashes, then you cannot account for that on DBMS level, which I'd personally consider problematic.

Comment: This can also make possible registration processes vulnerable if you don't take additional measures, for example if you'd just show an error when an already existing username/password combination is chosen, then you would have basically disclosed that users password.

Comment: I completely agree with your comments. Unfortunately, the user can define his own username and password, switching to email-login is not an option since we have to switch accounts to different emails (don't ask why). So the best thing for now is accepting the small chance that username and password are identical over different accounts. (what should result in an error)